# Compare json files but ignore values

Tags: jq

I would like to compare two json files and report differencies but I am interested in keys only and **not** values. So for example the "json-diff" between the following two files (of course they are much more complicated):

```
{
    "http": {
        "https": true,
        "swagger": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "scalingFactors": [0.1, 0.2]
    }
}
```

```
{
    "http": {
        "https": true,
        "swagger": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "scalingFactors": [0.1, 0.1],
        "test": true
    }
}
```

**should report** that there is missing key:

- `http.test`

but

**should not report** that the following keys have different values:

- `http.swagger.enabled`
- `http.scalingFactors`

I looked at the `jq` tool but I am not sure how to ignore values.

Comment: Can you please share your JSON model, Is it just having arrays? if yes, how do you want to handle them?

Comment: Would `jq '[paths] - [input | paths]' file1.json file2.json` be of use? [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5fmzJfI3Q8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring potential complications having to do with arrays, looking at the "symmetric difference" of the sets of paths to scalars would make sense. As a starting point, you could thus consider:

```
jq -c '
 [paths(scalars)] as $f1
 | [input | paths(scalars)] as $f2
 | ($f1 - $f2) + ($f2 - $f1)' file1.json file2.json
```

You might want to stringify the paths, but then again, it might be wise to avoid doing so if the mapping to the strings is not invertible.

---

If arrays are present, you might want to compare the paths while ignoring the array indices:

```
def p: [paths(scalars) | map(select(type=="string"))] | unique;
p as $f1
| (input | p) as $f2
| ($f1 - $f2) + ($f2 - $f1)
| .[]
```

The last line ensures that the result is a (possibly empty) stream, the point being that this makes it easy to check the return code to determine whether any difference was detected: simply use the -e command-line option.  If there are no differences, the return code will then be 4.

One way to check if the stream is empty would be to use the -4

Comment: I tested it with our jsons and indeed there is a problem with arrays. What would be required to make it working with arrays as well ?

Comment: pb100 - You have apparently not yet responded to the very first "comment" above.

Comment: Which comment ? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576552/compare-json-files-but-ignore-values/71580179#comment126503737_71576552) ?

Comment: Yes, that is the very first comment.

Comment: I am struggling with this question as I am not sure what is the json model and how to describe it.

Comment: pb100 - In a nutshell, what are your expectations when arrays are present?  Does Part 2 of my answer meet your requirements? Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.

Comment: peak - I have just updated the json content. Your part 2 almost works - when you use the code above you will see that is fails on "http.swagger.enabled"

Comment: in addition - I can see that in order to test whether it failed or not is to use i.e.: `wc` or `grep` ?

Comment: pb100 - See the update regarding how to use the return code to perform the test.